# Flutter import 'package:adobe_xd/pinned.dart' - Target of URI doesn't exist: ... (missing lib in the adobe_xd package?) How to solve it?

Tags: flutter, adobe-xd

I am using Flutter with VSCODE in a MacOS.
Just imported a file `MobileHomePage.dart` from **AdobeXD** and the file name is in RED - meaning some error in this file.
[image]

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqBwuJUYNcI&t=197s). At 5:33 it shows that I should add the follow packages (`adobe_xd: ^0.1.4` and `flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"`) in `pubspec.yaml` > `dependencies:` and `dev_dependencies:`. And now this is what I have:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  adobe_xd: ^0.1.4
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  adobe_xd: ^0.1.4
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"
```

Based on the video, at this point the VSCode should solve the problem (turning the color in withe) automatically. It does't happened. I still have the color in Red.

Digging inside the file `MobileHomePage.dart` I have an error in the `import 'package:adobe_xd/pinned.dart';`

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:adobe_xd/pinned.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist
```

I've try to locate this lib in the `flutter/adobe_xd` package and it doesn't exist.

```
~/Documents/vhosts/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/adobe_xd-0.1.4/lib(stable)$ ll
total 48
drwxr-xr-x   7 ialves  27132083   224 29 Aug 11:31 .
drwx------  10 ialves  27132083   320 29 Aug 11:31 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 ialves  27132083   494 13 May 16:15 adobe_xd.dart
-rw-r--r--   1 ialves  27132083  1884 13 May 16:57 blend_mask.dart
-rw-r--r--   1 ialves  27132083  1865 13 May 17:20 gradient_xd_transform.dart
-rw-r--r--   1 ialves  27132083  5685 13 May 17:20 page_link.dart
-rw-r--r--   1 ialves  27132083  1022 13 May 16:15 specific_rect_clip.dart
```

The `import 'package:adobe_xd/blend_mask.dart';` inside the `MobileHomePage.dart` file is not throwing an error because the lib `blend_mask.dart` already exists in `adobe_xd-0.1.4/lib`. But the lib `adobe_xd/pinned.dart` don't.

Maybe this is the origin of the issue.

I have tried: `flutter clean` and `flutter packages get` and restarted the VSCode and it didn't work. The `adobe_xd/pinned.dart` can't still be located.

I don't know how to solve this issue (install this missing lib in the adobe_xd package ?). Any idea?

---

Opened issue in [GtHub - AdobeXD
/
xd-to-flutter-plugin](https://github.com/AdobeXD/xd-to-flutter-plugin/issues/74).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `pubspec.yaml` change the adobe_xd version to this

```yaml
adobe_xd: ^1.0.0+1
```

Run `flutter pub upgrade` and `flutter clean` and you should be good

Answer (score 2):

1. Install Pubspec Assist extension from extensions.
2. Go to pubspec.yaml and hit CTRL+SHIFT+P
3. Search for **pubspec** in the opened line and select Pubspec Assist: Add/update Dependencies [input line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Qzp.png)
4. Enter adobe_xd in the line and it will automatically add the latest version to depencies

Answer (score 0):

**change your sdk version to 2.10.4**

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.4 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  adobe_xd: ^1.0.0+1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

### I have this config working for me:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  adobe_xd: ^1.0.0+1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```